# How to use media.Metadata class in android to get info from metadata of a video

Tags: android

I have a project in android that requires me to get bitrate of a streaming video that will be played in MediaPlayer. I concluded android.media.Metadata class (not in public API) will help me. But i am clueless about how to use it as a method of MediaPlayer.To get metadata of a file i can use MediaMetadataRetriver class. But how to use it with the external Metadata class?

Comment: hi @Brightspectra you found any solution for this?